# How to make something generative / procedural like this? Slint Spiderland Art / FutureNeue

Tags: procedural-art

Pretty new here, but have had stackexchange pop up enough on Google to know that this is probably the right place to ask this.

I've long been intimidated by anything procedural / generative, but have also admired a lot of it. Especially the kinetic stuff nowadays. Anyways - I've loved this Slint Spiderland generative art cover piece for a long time, and have always wondered....

[image: by FutureNeue https://www.instagram.com/futurneue/]

How do you go about making something like that?

The closest reference I have is some Fractal stuff from AE...I know there's dedicated fractal software like Chaotica, Apophysis, etc - is that it? This looks a bit more random and organic though.

Is it best done in something like Processing or 3js? Or good old PS/IL/AE?

Really kind of unsure where to begin here but in general am very into this sort of chaotic yet organized type of thing and would love to be able to play with making my own one day.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I don't know how this was generated, but have you considered that it might be a photograph of a real texture such as marble, or perhaps even something created by dripping paint/ink onto a surface? There's no way to tell for sure, but if I were going to design something similar, I wouldn't just assume it was created digitally.

Comment: Could even be cobwebs, given the context.

Comment: How is it generative work? (or what is it generated from?) This might help to find the answer...I think your processing lead is a good one though I'm not very familiar with it. It's been on my list of things to learn for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a workshop with Swiss designer who wanted to make nice Matterhorn silhouette but it always came up to close to Tomblerone.

So he taken a handkerchief, crumbled it and xero'ed. Then he just cut aproximate shape of a mountain.
He said "You need to see what you want not want what you see".

Because I wouldn't say that the image in your question is procedurally generated. I would say it might be ink drippage. It might be some long fibre fabric with contrast and brigthness really spiked up. Maybe the webbings that is created when you pull the taffy in your hands?

Looking at the fragment on the right I would even say it's marble veins (again with some touchup). I see in the comment that Billy Kerr had similar ideas.

Do not look for tool for that because there might be none. Look for what you want to see. Think what you want to have.
You write

> This looks a bit more random and organic

So turn to organic things. Natural. Look for chaos that create patterns. When I was studying I made a series "Stop watching the tv and go outside" where I would take pictures of nature and turn them into black & white so they resembled static noise. It was granite, snow, field of grass. A TV screen in the nature. I wanted to see that and I seen it.
And made others see it as well.